# Has_one or Has_many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have four models.

```
Application, Permission, User and AppPermissions
```

My AppPermission looks like:

```
AppPermission   Application    Permission   User
      1              1              1         1
      2              1              2         2
      3              1              3         3
      4              1              4         4
```

So an Application can have different permission from different Users.

```
Model: AppPermission:
belongs_to :application
belongs_to :permission
belongs_to :user
```

What about Application , Permission and User ? Where to use has_many through or has_one through?

Comment: you only need associations you will use. What kind of relationships do you need to implement?

Answer (score 0):

```
Application:
has_many :users
has_many :permissions
```

For users, you need more information, do you have more than one application? if so then:

```
User:
has_many :applications
has_many :appPermissions

Permission:
has_many :appPermissions
belongs_to :application
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see use case for having `has_many :through` with a three-way association. What a point having all permissions for a user without mentioning what application they are for? Most probably you will need queries like:

`user.app_permissions.find_all_by_application_id(application).map(&:permission)`

or

`user.app_permissions.find_by_application_id_and_permission_id(application, permission)`

All you need for these queries:

```
User:
has_many :app_permissions

AppPermission:
belongs_to :permission
```